# Customize event rendering in react-native-calendars?

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm building an app and am using [react-native-calendars](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars).  I'm wanting to add the event name and an image/icon to the event that spans across multiple days.  Something similar to this:

[image]

How can I do this using react-native-calendars?